# How do I fix a  motherboard error 02 on an EVGA 123-yw-e175-a1?

Tags: motherboard, hardware-failure, post

I have a motherboard `123-yw-e750-a1`.  When I turn it on, it just hangs with a POST code of 02.

I've tried removing different components, but it's still the same.  I tried a new hard drive and it booted but no OS was found.

I shut it down, thinking it was the hard drive but when I restarted it, it was the same thing.  It went to POST code 02.

Comment: Did you try a different hard drive controller? When you removed stuff, what did you remove and what did you leave in? Do you still get the same post code no matter what the configuration of hardware is? What is giving the post code 02, a test card or the mobo itself? what does that code reference in the manual for whichever device gives it?

Answer (score 1):

Asus says code 02 is a micro-code problem.  Micro-code is in the CPU.
My AMD Ryzen 1800x produced the same code on both an Asus and then a Gigabyte motherboard.  I changed hard drives, power supplies and connecting cables too.   Still got a code 02 and so I swapped out that Ryzen for a 1200x and everything works fine.  So the problem is within the CPU. Just applied for a warranty.

Answer (score 0):

If you switched the hard drive, and it got past boot - then it seems like the hard drive is the offender.

If no OS was found, you either have corrupted boot files or your drive needs an OS to begin with.